# Flutter has exited unexpectedly, Error reading dependency

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Recently, my code has unexpectedly stopped compiling when I try to debug. I'm running Flutter v0.5.1

The only reason I can think of to explain this is as this happened after I moved my flutter SDK from my desktop to a seperate folder.

This is the error I receive:

```
Error reading dependency file C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Other\Flutter\myproject\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\snapshot_blob.bin.d: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Error reading dependency file C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Other\Flutter\myproject\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\snapshot_blob.bin.d: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Error reading dependency file C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Other\Flutter\myproject\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\snapshot_blob.bin.d: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Crash report written to C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Other\Flutter\myproject\flutter_14.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\flutter_windows_v0.5.1-beta\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 435
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\flutter_windows_v0.5.1-beta\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 12s
Gradle build failed: 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

This is the Flutter Log thats dumped in the `myproject` folder:

````
Flutter crash report; please file at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

## command

flutter build bundle --suppress-analytics --target C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Other\Flutter\myproject\lib\main.dart --preview-dart-2 --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --depfile C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Other\Flutter\myproject\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug/snapshot_blob.bin.d --asset-dir C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Other\Flutter\myproject\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug/flutter_assets

## exception

RangeError: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

```
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/dart:core/growable_array.dart:141)
#1      readDepfile (package:flutter_tools/src/base/fingerprint.dart:174)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Fingerprinter._getPaths (package:flutter_tools/src/base/fingerprint.dart:88)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Fingerprinter.doesFingerprintMatch (package:flutter_tools/src/base/fingerprint.dart:60)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      KernelCompiler.compile (package:flutter_tools/src/compile.dart:104)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      build (package:flutter_tools/src/bundle.dart:79)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      BuildBundleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_bundle.dart:72)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:344)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:279)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#12     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#13     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:270)
#15     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:194)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:309)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#19     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#20     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#21     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:265)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:109)
#24     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:222)
#25     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:109)
#26     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:174)
#27     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:59)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142)
<asynchronous suspension>
#29     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#30     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#31     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#32     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141)
<asynchronous suspension>
#33     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#34     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50)
#35     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:49)
<asynchronous suspension>
#36     main (file:///E:/b/build/slave/Windows_Flutter_Packaging/build/archive/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8)
#37     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:277)
#38     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165)
```

## flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 0.5.1 at C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\flutter_windows_v0.5.1-beta\flutter
    • Framework revision c7ea3ca377 (3 months ago), 2018-05-29 21:07:33 +0200
    • Engine revision 1ed25ca7b7
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.25.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • HTC Desire 510 • CC58XY408727 • android-arm • Android 4.4.3 (API 19)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```
````

The errors; `✗ Flutter plugin not installed; ✗ Dart plugin not installed` shouldn't be an issue, they are both installed according to VSCode and apparently this issue, due to case sensitive values not being recognised by `flutter doctor`, affects everyone on VSCode.

Comment: You answered yourself - "Error reading dependency file C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Other\Flutter"

Comment: "✗ Dart plugin not installed shouldn't be an issue," is fixed in newer Flutter versions.

Comment: Do you know how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: Not sure what causes it. Have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: Never mind, I changed the directory and ran `flutter clean` in the console. This worked perfectly and fixed the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was fixed after Günter suggested a `flutter clean`.

Answer (score 3):

Follow below steps issue will be fixed
Change your Flutter channel to Master using below command

flutter channel master

the execute below command

flutter run

the issue will be solved and your dart version will be updated

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in ubuntu 20.04
I changed my path to directory with no space now problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following steps. That worked for me. Only for Mac users.

Step 1: Remove Podfiles by
In mac

```
       i) rm ios/Podfile
      ii) rm ios/Podfile.lock
```

Step 2: Run ***flutter clean*** . It will remove the build folder and cleanup the project.

Step 3: Generate Podfiles by ***flutter run***

Note: Don't use ***Pod init*** for Generate Podfile,
Because it doesn't create any dependancies.

Optional Step 4: If the Podfiles already generated then we can update it by ***pod install*** and ***pod update***.
Also please make sure you are in ios folder.

```
   i)   cd ios
   ii)  pod install
   iii) pod update
```

**Note**: Please make sure flutter_svg dependency should be flutter_svg: ^0.18.0 in pubspec.yaml